# For Facebook advertising, should I spend money on ads or promoting posts?

Tags: seo, marketing

I am working with a start up that has relatively few (~600) likes for their Facebook page.

The end goal is to get people using the startup's site regularly.  I realize a potent way to get people to the site is to have compelling content that can be promoted in posts.  However, from what I understand, if you have a lot of likes for your Facebook page, then it is much cheaper to promote a post to that audience.

So, given that this is early in the game, where do I spend the money?  Do I run ads to try to build up a large base of Facebook page likes and THEN promote posts?  Or do I simply forgo the ads and put all the money into promoted posts?

Comment: This is not related to Pro Webmasters.

Comment: I'd love a way to rephrase this so as to enable the responses to be less opinion based.  It feels like there should a basic right path to doing things.  Focusing all add dollars in increasing FB page likes seems wrong as it doesn't get people to the site.  Focusing all dollars on posts doesn't build community - with a very large community you wouldn't necessarily have to pay to promote posts.

Comment: But it IS opinion-based. And also off-topic.

Comment: William, I'm also also all ears in terms of which Stack Exchange property would be best to ask this question.  I posted here based on [this quora post](http://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-Stack-Exchange-like-site-for-SEO-web-marketing)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a relative question that only you and your client can agree upon. Obviously not the answer you're looking for, so my suggestion would be the following.

Continue growing your FB fan base within the area that is likely to be the highest-engaging (whether it be geographical or interest-related).

However, I would, in conjunction, promote posts that have high potential to engage with your audience (i.e. whitepaper, free trial, or some other incentive).

I always go back to the 80/20 rule that users want 80% (probably more) engaging content rather than hearing about your business. If it's personalized and tied in with your overall strategy, that should set you up for some pretty good metrics moving forward.